# How to select an element in a JSON array dinamically within a for loop?

Tags: arrays, json, for-loop, append, placeholder

I created a webpage which is a search form basically.
The user has to type the name of a city in a text field and click a search button; whenever such string is included in a specific list of cities the user may click on another button to search for hotels in that city.

I'm exploiting two JSON files in order to do that: the former comes from an API search, the latter is a static one created by myself; in order to display info from both I wrote two `for loop` functions and used the `.append()` method twice so that the info of both JSON files are displayed consequentially into the same `tbody`, see the code below:

```
var readHotel = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/prove/pagine_bianche/searchpb?client=pbbrowsing&version=4.0&device=evo&pagesize=25&output=json&lang=it&typedwhat=hotel&what=hotel&where=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()),
        dataType: "json",   

        success: function (data) {
            $("#tbody2").empty();    

            for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                let hotel = data.results[i];

                $("#tbody2").append("<tr><td>" + hotel.lastname + "</td><td>" + hotel.phones[0].number + "</td></tr>");
                $("#tabella2").show();
                $("#thead2").show();
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation.length; i++) {


                    $("#tbody2").append("<tr><td>" + lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation[i].name + "</td><td>" + lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation[i].city + "</td></tr>")

            }
                $("#hotel").prop("disabled", false);
        }  
    });
};
```

I previously created a variable `lowCostHotels` which holds the whole content of the JSON file:

```
var readLowCostAccomodation = function () {

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost/prove/low_cost_hotels.json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("ajax call readLowCostAccomodation() has been activated");
            lowCostHotels = data;
        }
    })
};
```

The code works, i.e. the required info is displayed correctly.

What I need to do now is to select the info of the second JSON file to be displayed, i.e.: I want to display the info about the specific city the user has searched for.
I need to keep the `for loop` function to cycle all the elements of the JSON array, but I need to display just one of them. 
To be more precise, the second JSON file has the following structure (I just write a part of it, for reasons of brevity):

```
{
  "LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation": [

    {
      "name": "A Taberna Potami",
      "city": "TOPLECCA",
      "region": "Tuscany",
      "type": "Low Cost Pilgrim Accomodation",
      "tappa": "Pavia-Lucca"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ostello Castello del Piagnaro",
      "city": "PONTREMOLI",
      "region": "Tuscany",
      "type": "Low Cost Pilgrim Accomodation",
      "tappa": "Pavia-Lucca"
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON array above has 2 elements. Each element gives info about hotels in two different cities, TOPLECCA and PONTREMOLI.
All the elements of the array need to be cycled (they are 2, in this case), but I want to display just those which correspond to the string typed in the search form: if the user types "TOPLECCA", I want to display the info given by the first element; if he types "PONTREMOLI", I want to take the second one.

In order to do that, I suppose I need to use the `($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()` like as in the following, given that `inlineFormInputCitta` is the ID given to the input form/ text field:

```
if ($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val() === lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation[i].city) {}
```

...and then write into the curly brackets some function to tell the browser to take a specific

```
lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation[i].name
```

I was thinking about creating new variables to associate the key "city" of the JSON file to the key "name"(of the hotel), inside the if statement, but I'm not sure I'm on the right direction...

Any suggestion?

---

I added the if statement below but it doesn't work:

```
for (let i = 0; i < lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation.length; i++) {

                if ($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val() === lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation[i].city);

                {
                    var city = $("#inlineFormInputCitta").val();
                    var entry = lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation.find(function(entry) {
                        return entry.city === city;
                        return entry.name === name;
                    });

                    $("#tbody2").append("<tr><td>" + entry.name + "</td><td>" + entry.city + "</td></tr>")
                }
            }
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. (In your case, it *was* JSON, but then it got parsed by jQuery before being given to your code.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to get the city name, and I assume it's coming from an `input`element with the `id` you've used in your `$("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()` code.

Adding the `if` you've mentioned works, or you can use `find` to find the entry and not have the `for` loop at all, e.g.:

```
var city = $("#inlineFormInputCitta").val();
var entry = lowCostHotels.LOW_COST_Pilgrim_accomodation.find(function(entry) {
    return entry.city === city;
});
if (entry) {
    // Use `entry.name`, etc. here
} else {
    // There was no match
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, that was the ID of the input element, I added the info in the Question

Comment: I added the function but I get an error (I updated the Q)

Comment: @franz1 - That means there was no entry matching on `city`. (Your second `return` statement in that screenshot will never be executed. If you want to check both `city` and `name`, you need to do `return entry.city === city && entry.name === name;`)